# Loading AJAX with slide effect

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

My plan is to have a content DIV, and inside that div I will load content via AJAX. I want the already loaded page to slide to the left, fade in the loading page with the circle.gif, and then fade in the new content and so on for the rest of the pages.

I have this code, but it goes to the top not the left, there is no scrollLeft I think.

```
$("#someDiv").slideUp("slow").load('blah.html', function() {
    $(this).slideDown("slow");
});
```

And there is this one:

```
$('.cont a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.p-list').prepend('<div class="loader"> </div>');
        $('.p-list').slideUp("slow").load(page +" .proj", function() {
             $(this).fadeIn("slow"); //or show or slideDown
        });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Consider using CSS for animations, unless it is crucial to the functionality of the application.

Comment: Could you show a [fiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) of your code?

Comment: hi, here is my try out

http://jsfiddle.net/viciosogb/DPrb5/

Comment: I cant it to work neither changing the order or jsfiddle is not adecuate to check this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `animate` with `left` property like this:

```
$("#someDiv").slideUp("slow").load('blah.html', function() {
    $(this).animate({'left' : 'show'});
});
```

You can also use `right`, `margin-left`, `margin-right` with `show` as value depending on your needs.

To hide them back with horizontal sliding, use `hide` value instead.

Make sure that elements are hidden first and have set appropriate CSS values for those properties.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, here is a try out of what Im looking to achieve

http://jsfiddle.net/viciosogb/DPrb5/